# JavaScript: some unwanted text comes in the input box when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html

On this page, when the page on load, i reset the value of all the input boxes and make the `focus` on to the first input box such as `user-name`. But, here, somewhat unwanted text comes such as `dwd` on `user-name` box and as well as in the password field whenever the page loads. The `placeholder`is not coming whenever the page loads. what is the mistake here? Please see the image

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    </head>
  <body>

    <form name="loginForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="Firstname Lastname"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm password"/><br/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/><br/>
    <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="Website"/><br/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">    

window.onload = function(){
document.getElementsByName("user-name")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("password1")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value="";
document.getElementById("FormSubmit").style.display="none";
document.getElementsByName("user-name")[0].focus();
}

var formElem = document.getElementsByName("loginForm")[0];
formElem.onsubmit = function(){
var returnValue=true;
if (loginForm["user-name"].value.length < 6 ){
returnValue = false;
alert("dshddhhdhdhh");
return returnValue;
}
}</script>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It might be done by a password manager in the client side... disable all extentions in the browser and try

Comment: did you try placing the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the text inputs?